# Не получается установить pyinstaller

Tags: python, windows, pip, pyinstaller, install

Пытаюсь установить `pyinstaller` через pip, но не получается.

Python:3.8.6 (на Python:3.8.7 тоже самое)

Cистема:Windows 7

Тип системы:64 бит

Вот что происходит

```
C:\Users\александр>pip install pyinstaller
Collecting pyinstaller
  Using cached pyinstaller-4.2.tar.gz (3.6 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
    Preparing wheel metadata ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\games\python.exe' 'c:\games\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep5
17\_in_process.py' prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel 'C:\Users\8B1D~1\AppData\Loc
al\Temp\tmpwu4xtqvf'
         cwd: C:\Users\александр\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-pclf4oph\pyinsta
ller
    Complete output (38 lines):
    running dist_info
    creating C:\Users\александр\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-72o6vl2y\
pyinstaller.egg-info
    writing C:\Users\александр\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-72o6vl2y\p
yinstaller.egg-info\PKG-INFO
    writing dependency_links to C:\Users\александр\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern
-metadata-72o6vl2y\pyinstaller.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
    writing entry points to C:\Users\александр\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-met
adata-72o6vl2y\pyinstaller.egg-info\entry_points.txt
    writing requirements to C:\Users\александр\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-met
adata-72o6vl2y\pyinstaller.egg-info\requires.txt
    writing top-level names to C:\Users\александр\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-
metadata-72o6vl2y\pyinstaller.egg-info\top_level.txt
    writing manifest file 'C:\Users\александр\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-meta
data-72o6vl2y\pyinstaller.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    reading manifest file 'C:\Users\александр\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-meta
data-72o6vl2y\pyinstaller.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
    Error in sitecustomize; set PYTHONVERBOSE for traceback:
    SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe0 in positio
n 0: invalid continuation byte (sitecustomize.py, line 21)
    warning: no files found matching 'pyinstaller-gui.py'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'bootloader\build'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'bootloader\.waf-*'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'bootloader\.waf3-*'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'bootloader\waf-*'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'bootloader\waf3-*'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'bootloader\_sdks'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'bootloader\.vagrant'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching 'bootloader\.lock-waf*'

    no previously-included directories found matching 'doc\source'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'doc\_build'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.tmp' found under directory
 'doc'
    warning: no files found matching 'news\_template.rst'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'news'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'old'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'scripts'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'tests\scripts'
    no previously-included directories found matching '.github'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.*'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '*.yml'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '*~'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.directory'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.py[co]' found anywhere in
distribution
    writing manifest file 'C:\Users\александр\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-meta
data-72o6vl2y\pyinstaller.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    creating 'C:\Users\александр\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-72o6vl2y
\pyinstaller.dist-info'
    error: invalid command 'bdist_wheel'
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\games\python.exe' 'c:\games\l
ib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py' prepare_metadata_for_build_w
heel 'C:\Users\8B1D~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpwu4xtqvf' Check the logs for full co
mmand output.
WARNING: You are using pip version 20.2.1; however, version 21.0 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'c:\games\python.exe -m pip install --upgr
ade pip' command.
```

Пожалуйста напишите как решить проблему.

Comment: Не знаю точно, с чем связана эта ошибка, но могу предположить -  из-за того что у вас в пути есть кириллица, точнее ваш юзер - на русском языке. Попробуйте изменить юзера на латиницу, или создать нового юзера.

Comment: WARNING: You are using pip version 20.2.1; however, version 21.0 is available.

Comment: Для начала обновите pip если не поможет есть вариант поменять юзера, или  переустановить python.

Answer (score 1):

эта команда точно поможет
pip install wheel